# How to make div's made up into grid stay where they are when one of them becomes larger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a grid of same height tiles that can be expanded on click. To make the rest of the div's stay in their position when one is expanded, I gave it `margin-bottom: -100px`.

However, when a div expands, all below him, just for a second, change their position, after that they come back.

I though about setting a fixed position for each of them using JS, but then I realized that I need the page to be resizeable, so I cannot execute Javascript every time.

Could you give me any advises on how to make a div overlay his neighbors without changing their position?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SkaN/0xp6eztf/2/)

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 I'll try, the code is just so messy, 2 people have been working on it, I'll try to bring only relevant parts.

Comment: @SkaN Can include rendered `html` elements at Question ? Create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I found that there is no way to have what I want at this moment, so involving some JS I got this:

```
$('.expand:has(.open:visible)').click(function()
{
    var button, backdrop, postOriginal, post;

    button       = $(this);
    backdrop     = $('.backdrop');
    postOriginal = button.parents('.post-single');
    post         = postOriginal.clone().addClass('expanded');

    post.css(
        {
            top: ( postOriginal.position().top + $('.widget-container').scrollTop() ) + 'px',
            left: postOriginal.position().left + 'px'
        }
    );

    backdrop.fadeIn().before(post);

    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        post.css(
            {
                top: ( postOriginal.position().top + $('.widget-container').scrollTop() ) + 'px',
                left: postOriginal.position().left + 'px'
            }
        );
    });

    $('.backdrop, .expand:has(.notOpen:visible)').click(function(event)
    {
        $('.backdrop').fadeOut()
            .prev().remove();

        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

    return false;
});
```

It clones the post tile, gives it an exact position as it's original and overlays it, so it looks like the post it expanded, but in fact it's just copied.

Answer (score 1):

So, I looked at your code and found the error. The CSS code hosts a `margin-bottom` of -256px. Basically, you are getting that bounce back everytime you click on a `div` you are pulling your content above the top clicked content by 256 pixels. To check for yourself I have made the adjustments showing you what 256px looks like on the class `.posts-container .post-single.expanded`([here](https://jsfiddle.net/0xp6eztf/15/))

This is a simple fix, just get rid of the -256px and put 1px. I made the adjustment here([here](https://jsfiddle.net/0xp6eztf/13/))